# When I open the second form within the first one, it doesn't work properly (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, mdi

I have two forms in my project (a simple game for kids). The first one is the start menu and the second one is the game. Now, when I click on New Game, I want the second form to open within the first one. I did that by using the following code:

```
  private Form activeForm = null;
        private void openChildForm(Form childForm1)
        {
            if (activeForm!=null)
            {
                activeForm.Close();
            }
            activeForm = childForm1;
            childForm1.TopLevel = false;
            childForm1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(childForm1);
            panel1.Tag = childForm1;
            childForm1.BringToFront();
            childForm1.Show();


        }
```

Now the second form opens within the first one, but it doesn't work properly. In my second form I have a picturebox, which is supposed to move when the user presses on one of the arrow keys. But it won't move.

Any suggestions what should I do?

P.S. 
I'm a beginner and this is a school project. My teacher showed us only one way of opening a form:

```
Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
objForm2.Show();
```

but since it is a very ugly method of getting the job done, I wanted to do it better.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Uh, what's ugly about using `Show()` exactly?  And if you want to do this `panel1.Controls.Add(childForm1);` you should create a user control, not form.

Comment: You can search either for ShowDialog();

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
What I meant by ugly is that if I open my second form that way, then I have 2 forms on my screen (which is ugly for me). And I can also hide the first one after showing the second one, but that doesn't feel right (I don't want the user to see that another window opens and the last one disappears).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a so called [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) it's basically that what the name says: It's a custom windows forms control, witch has it's own child controls -> Just Like a form.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jannes.
I'll see what I can do.